# Qual a origem da expressão "pito que nunca viu canhoto?"

Tags: expressões-idiomáticas, origem

Soube que significa "alguém de classe social menos privilegiada, que ficou rico" mas não consigo entender porque "pito" e porque "canhoto".

PS Após ter postado a pergunta descobri que é uma expressão cabo-verdiana e não portuguesa conforme havia pensado. Como isso não invalida a questão, deixo postada para o caso de alguém saber a resposta.

Comment: Soubeste como? Não conheço essa expressão. Usa-se no Brasil?

Comment: @Jacinto Engano meu. Pensei que fosse uma expressão portuguesa mas é cabo verdiana.  Talvez alguem nativo das ilhas saiba explicar.

Comment: A tua fonte de informação parece não ser muito fiável. "Pito que nunca viu canhoto" não significa "alguém de classe social menos privilegiada que ficou rico."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A expressão é cabo-verdiana, como já sabemos. [***Canhoto***](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/canhoto) é em Cabo Verde um cachimbo: tem origem no português *canudo*, via crioulo guineense. As minhas fontes cabo-verdianas informam-me que ***pito*** é a parte amovível do cachimbo que vai à boca. Quando se sabe, até é fácil encontrar:

> Nós dois muito camaradas, nhô Chic’Ana dentando o pito do cachimbo (Escritor cabo-verdiano [Baltazar Lopes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baltasar_Lopes_da_Silva), [*Chiquinho*](http://linhasdeespuma.blogspot.pt/2010/12/baltasar-lopes-materiais-de-apoio.html), 1947.)

Ora estar como ***pito que nunca viu canhoto*** é estar excitadíssimo, deslumbrado, fascinado com uma novidade qualquer, como se vê nos exemplos abaixo. A expressão aprece com frequência na obra do escritor cabo-verdiano [Germano Almeida](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germano_Almeida):

> (…) perfume que parece desprender-se de Júlia (…) é assim que parece a nhô Pepe que continua respirando-a extasiado, abrindo com despudor as narinas em direção a ela sem esconder quanto a essência que respira o excita física e mentalmente.
> Júlia acabou por rir desse espalhafato num homem aparentemente tão sério, Bocê está como ***pito que nunca viu canhoto***, disse (Germano Almeida, [Do Monte Cara Vê-se o Mundo](https://books.google.pt/books?id=UPmYBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT29&lpg=PT29&dq=%22pito%20que%20nunca%20viu%20canhoto%22&source=bl&ots=3JGwv0RDBt&sig=fn3G1xGMyMapeJAafocxeO-KcEs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-ue_8pdbJAhXCMBoKHVl6C6EQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22pito%20que%20nunca%20viu%20canhoto%22&f=false), 2014)

Neste outro romance, o Sr. Napumocemo, depois de uma vida a trabalhar, viaja pelo mundo, fica fascinado com maravilhas da técnica, como gravadores de mensagens, e volta a Cabo Verde:

> (…) Carlos disse a Maria da Graça ter assistido de sorriso irónico a toda essa mudança no caráter do Sr. Napumocemo e acompanhado a instalação de todas essas bardamerdices. Nessa febre técnica [o Sr. Napumocemo] parecia um maluco fugido do manicómio, ***pito que nunca viu canhoto*** (Germano Almeida, [*O Testamento do Sr. Napumocemo da Silva Araújo*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=SA_erlQQf1kC&pg=PT42&lpg=PT42&dq=Naquela%20febre%20t%C3%A9cnica%20parecia%20um%20maluco%20fugido%20do%20manic%C3%B3mio&source=bl&ots=ajQID4tuAO&sig=x6N6lmIwHwoK381mid4u4gsj6JU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjowaSmoNbJAhXHlxoKHbQhC9EQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=Naquela%20febre%20t%C3%A9cnica%20parecia%20um%20maluco%20fugido%20do%20manic%C3%B3mio&f=false), 1991)

Outros exemplos:

> Aqui o que está em jogo é a descaracterização do centro histórico do Mindelo que está sempre no altar dos sacrifícios. É mais uma bomba nessa cidade. E como sempre os mindelenses conformam-se muito depressa e é por isso é que apanham sempre tareia. Ficaram todos maravilhados com o prédio que nada tem a ver com o espaço. É “***pito que nunca viu canhoto***” está dito. [(Éden Park: o renascer da Fénix)](http://noticiasdonorte.publ.cv/21357/eden-park-o-renascer-da-fenix/)
>
> Tanta euforia de um lado e do outro, embora por motivos diversos, traz-me à lembrança aquela frase: "***pito que nunca viu canhoto***". Tenham calma. [(*Café Margoso*)](http://cafemargoso.blogspot.pt/2010/05/sms-cafeano.html)

Comment: Acho que temos um ditado semelhante em ptBR mas não consigo lembrar.